# how to show image from server without downloading it android

Tags: java, android

I am building an Android app that will show images - based on exact GPS location.

My idea is to show these images from server **without downloading** them to phone. That way you can view them only if you have downloaded that app and have internet access.

Is it possible in Android??

Comment: There is nothing like buffering in case of images.In any case your images will get downloaded/cached to local storage.

Answer (score 0):

YEs.. You can load them in a webview:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: > That way you can view them only if you have downloaded that app  >and have internet access.
My point was to show images only if you have downloaded the app. webview will just display images from a web page...